# Where is Laerakond ("Returned Abeir") after the Second Sundering?

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms, lore, maps

The [Forgotten Realms wiki entry on Laerakond](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Laerakond) says:

> Laerakond [...] was a large, horseshoe-shaped landmass, west of the Trackless Sea and north of the Great Sea. (...) Laerakond was located near Evermeet, in the Great Sea the to the south of the elven island.

The entry on the [Trackless Sea](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Trackless_Sea) says:

> The Trackless Sea was the name of the ocean due west of the continent of Faerûn. [...] The Trackless Sea ran from the Sea of Swords in the west [east?] to Maztica, [...] and Anchorome in the east [west?].

The [Great Sea](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Great_Sea) entry says:

> The Great Sea was [...] lying between the continents of Faerûn and Zakhara, and, after the Spellplague of 1385 DR, between those two continents and the new continent of Laerakond.

And the entry on [Anchorome](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Anchorome) says:

> Anchorome [...] is the far western continent of Toril. It lies roughly 3,000 miles (4,800 km) west across the Trackless Sea of the Sword Coast, or about 1,000 miles (1,600 km) west of Evermeet. Anchorome is directly north of Maztica.

According to [Ed Greenwood](http://forum.candlekeep.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=12023&whichpage=66&SearchTerms=identical) (via [The Hooded One](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/The_Hooded_One), his spokesperson on Candlekeep Forum):

> Returned Abeir becomes the identical continent of Laerakond, well southwest of Evermeet

From all that chaos, I can imagine the Great Sea stretching between the shores of Faerun, Zakhara, and Maztica, with Laerakond being somewhere near the Chult - Maztica line, quite close to Maztica (less that 500 miles) according to Ed's description and the size of Laerakond, which different maps estimate at around 1000 miles.

**Is my deduction correct? Am I missing something?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, it's in the northernmost part of the Great Sea

You did a great job of chaining together all of the references, and I believe your logic is correct, as it is supported by additional references as well.

In the [Great Sea](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Great_Sea) entry:

> After the Spellplague of 1385 DR, the continent of Laerakond appeared in its northern boundary.

And because the Great Sea in its north-south dimension stretches from near Chult southward toward Zakhara (that Zakhara is far south of Chult is attested in the Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide, pp. 11, 14), therefore the Great Sea's "northern boundary" is indeed roughly a Chult-Maztica line.

And Greenwood's "well southwest of Evermeet" quote pushes it closer to Maztica, as you've indicated.

Therefore your deduction seems right on to me.